# Join on specific key not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have four tables like this:

- schoolyear (**id**)
- student (**id**, *schoolyear_id*)
- test (**id**)
- grade (**id**, *test_id*, *student_id*, score)

A student is associated with a `schoolyear` (through fk), and a grade is associated with a `test` and a `student` through fk's.

I want all students for a particular schoolyear to be returned regardless, and join the test `score` for the student along with all other fields from the student table if it exists. If not, the `score` field should be null. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT *, `student`.`id` as `studentid`
FROM `student`
LEFT JOIN `grade` ON `grade`.`student_id` = `student`.`id` 
WHERE `student`.`schoolyear_id` = ?
```

There's nothing in my current statement telling it a particular test yet, but that's what I want.

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?  A little confusing as is to understand.

Comment: @sgeddes I'd like every field from the student table, as well as a field `rating` from that test.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, `student`.`id` as `studentid`, t.*
FROM `student`
LEFT JOIN `grade` ON `grade`.`student_id` = `student`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `test` t ON `t`.`id` = `grade`.`test_id` 
WHERE `student`.`schoolyear_id` = ?
and test_id = ?
```

Comment: Works, but does not return all students regardless of whether or not there is a score (my question was unclear so that's my fault).

Comment: when you say all students, you mean for all school years ?

Comment: No, `student` has a fk of `schoolyear_id`, so I only want that schoolyear's students.

Comment: I'm not sure I did understand you question, because for me this query shows all students for a specific school year, whether they toke a test or not. meanwhile try select student.*, t.* from...

Comment: I'm still only getting the students that have a score for the test.

Comment: Hmm, change (and test_id = ?) to (Or test_id = ?)

Comment: Tried that, returns all students now but returns for all tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67775/discussion-between-simo-and-nathan-francy).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the conditional to the ON clause. This will ensure that students stay included, even if there's no grade for that test.

```
SELECT g.*, s.id
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN Grade g
ON g.student_id = s.id
 AND g.id = ?
WHERE s.schoolyear_id  = ?
```